# I deleted my HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\cuttentversion\ProductName

Tags: regedit

I know i did a mistake ... 
I deleted my HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\cuttentversion\ProductName registry key ...
How can i retrieve the information in it ?

I did searched before posting ...

Answer (score 0):

Try using system restore, even if you dont have a specified checkpoint you can still rollback to a little bit.

If that doesnt work then you might as well either

A) save your stuff onto an hdd and reformatt.

B)Try to get a new registry key so that it will be re-added.[there are a few sites thatll give out keys]

I hope this helps you!